# exp function not recognized in Raster Calculator?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, expression

I am trying to preform a calculation for the exponential increase in cost of a slope, using the "exp" function, but get an "error parsing formula" message. The expression as I've written it is:

```
1000*(exp("Slope@1"*0.2)-1)
```

where "slope@1" is my tif file, and what I'm trying to calculate is essentially: `Slope_cost = $1000 * {Exp(slope_percent * 0.2) – 1}`

How/does the exponential function work on Raster Calculator? I'm using QGIS 3.8.3 Zanzibar version

Answer (score 2):

the exponent function is ^:

```
10^3=1000
10^-1=0.1
```

so it should be

```
1000*(("Slope@1"*0.2)^2.71828-1)
```

where e=2.71828